# Swagger Not populating @Apimodel annotation in model class level

Tags: java, spring, maven, swagger, springfox

I am using swagger in Java rest service.model class not populating `@apimodel` and `@apimodelproperty`. When I use of high swagger spring MVC version it populating. But, I am getting error like this version does not contain Documention config. How to reslove this problem.swagger spring MVC?

```
0.5.3 version pom.xml
Spring.xml
```

This bean contain inside of spring XML file.

```
<bean id="documentationConfig"
         class="com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.DocumentationConfig" />
```

controller HomeController.java

```
package com.example.anand.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.Api;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;

@Api(value = "main controller", description = "Endpoint for TEST Managemenent")
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/newfinalmvc")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addnew", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Addnew ", notes = "Add new Controller")
    public @ResponseBody Object addNew(@RequestBody hello hel) {
        String getName = hel.getName();
        System.out.println(getName);
        hello h1 = new hello();
        h1.setName(getName);
        return h1;
    }
}
```

Model class which helps to setter and getter
@Apimodel and @Apimodelproperty annotion not dispalying in model class level

```
public class hello {

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Why am I facing this problem?

Comment: Try moving to a newer version of [springfox](http://springfox.io). This is probably the oldest version of the library, that you're using.

Comment: ya i got answer .now i am using 0.8.2 spring mvc version

Comment: U should atleast be on 1.0.2 if not 2.x that's a very old version

Comment: for me 0.8.2 it working fine for me